# WPF MultiBinding to Background Property Not Working

Tags: wpf, background, converters, multibinding

MultiBinding to Background property does not work. When it is converted, the background simply turns to the system's default color, not what I have set in the MultiValueConverter. Everything else is set up propertly.  What's wrong with my MultiBinding to Background?

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={StaticResource triggerResource},
                                   Path=MyIsSelected}"         
                 Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource groupNameToBackgroundConv}">
                    <Binding Path="Name" />
                    <Binding Source="{StaticResource selectedGroupName}" Path="Name" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

And my MultiValueConverter is

```
 public class GroupNameToBackgroundConv : IMultiValueConverter
{
    private const string DEFAULT_COLOR = "#B8CBE9";
    private const string SELECTED_COLOR = "#FFFF00";       

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string groupName = values[0] as string;
        string selectedGroupName = values[1] as string;

        if (groupName == null)
            return DEFAULT_COLOR;

        if (selectedGroupName == null)
            return DEFAULT_COLOR;

        if (groupName == selectedGroupName)
        {
            return SELECTED_COLOR;
        }
        else
        {
            return DEFAULT_COLOR;
        }


    }  // ends method

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

} // ends class
```

Comment: Have you set a break point in your converter to see if `Convert` is being called?

Comment: Did you also set a background property for your style (not only for Trigger) e.g. <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/> ?

Comment: Yes. Convert is being called.

Comment: Yes. I also set a background property before the datatrigger.
 
<Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
<Setter Property="Background" Value="#B8CBE9" />
<Style.Triggers>
<DataTrigger ...

The problem is that the background turns to system's default color (not my default one or selected color) when triggered and converted. So it seems like the Background's Setter.Value cannot have a string (from converter).

Comment: and did you try the following: return (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(DEFAULT_COLOR);

Comment: @PiotrPtak that does not work either.   But if I directly put Red or #FFFF00 right under <Setter.Value> as the following code, it works. 

<Setter Property="Background">
                                                                        <Setter.Value>
       Red                                                                 </Setter.Value>
                                                                    </Setter>

Comment: I solved the problem.
When Convert returns a value, it needs to be Brush, not string or Color.

Comment: of course! How could I forgot that :-). Glad you made it to work!

Comment: @DanPyongAnByon: You should write that as answer and mark it as accepted - makes it more useful for others.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem.
When Convert returns a value, it needs to be Brush, not string or Color for
the background property of a control Expander.
Here is my converter.

```
 public class GroupNameToBackgroundConv : IMultiValueConverter
{

    private Color DEFAULT_COLOR = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#B8CBE9");
    private Color SELECTED_COLOR = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFFF00");       

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string groupName = values[0] as string;
        string selectedGroupName = values[1] as string;          

        if (groupName == null)
            return ColorOrBrush(DEFAULT_COLOR, targetType);

        if (selectedGroupName == null)
            return ColorOrBrush(DEFAULT_COLOR, targetType);

        if (groupName == selectedGroupName)
        {
            return ColorOrBrush(SELECTED_COLOR, targetType);
        }
        else
        {
            return ColorOrBrush(DEFAULT_COLOR, targetType);
        }



    }  // ends method


    private object ColorOrBrush(Color c, Type targetType)
    {
        if (targetType == typeof(Color))
            return c;
        else if (targetType == typeof(Brush))
            return new SolidColorBrush(c);
        else 
            return null;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

} // ends class
```